# small logical issue in this jquery code: "load" more pages with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have many `article` divs in news index page where each div contains a single news teaser.

I want to show first 10, then during scrolling down and reaching the bottom, i will show the another 10 etc etc.. this is my js.

```
$(function () {
  shown = 0;
  $('.artikel').hide();
  $('.artikel').each(function () {
    if (shown <= 10) {
        shown += 1;
        $(this).show();
    }
  });
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {

        setTimeout(function () {
            // problem here. 
            $('.artikel').each(function () {
                if (shown <= 20) {
                    shown += 1;
                    $(this).show();
                }
            });


        }, 1500);
    }
  });
});
```

the problem in my logic is, once i scroll to bottom, the function inside setTimeOut is counting all `article`s again from beginning.

I want that it shows the next 10 news beginning from the last shown article. can someone give a small help with this please?

Comment: Just after your if statement add `shown += 10` which should add 10 every time it refreshes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the first hidden article and then display 10 following articles, so you don't have to keep count of how many you've displayed so far:

```
var shownCount = 0;

$('.artikel:not(:visible)').each(function () {
    if (shownCount <= 10) {
        shownCount += 1;
        $(this).show();
    }
```